# Pass python list as parameter to MySQL.connector

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a query that I am trying to pass to python MySQL.connector like:

```
        cursor.execute("""
        SELECT x.Code as MatchCode,
            m.CUI,
            GROUP_CONCAT(m.CODE separator '|') Codes, 
            GROUP_CONCAT(m.SAB separator '|') Sources
            FROM umls.MRCONSO m,
            (SELECT * FROM umls.MRCONSO WHERE code in (%s)) x
        WHERE x.cui = m.cui and x.sab in (%s)
        GROUP BY m.CUI;
        """ % (mdr_format_strings, sab_format_strings), mdr_ids, sabs)
```

where `mdr_ids = ["1234", "5678"]` and `sabs=["Source1", "Source2"]`

I am trying to pass these as parameters in a `cursor.execute` statement but am having troubles.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One option might be combining those parameters by converting them to array of tuples such as

```
prm = [
    (1234,5678), 
    ('Source1','Source2')
    ]

cursor.execute("""
                  SELECT x.Code as MatchCode, m.CUI,
                         GROUP_CONCAT(m.CODE separator '|') Codes, 
                         GROUP_CONCAT(m.SAB separator '|') Sources
                    FROM umls.MRCONSO m
                    JOIN (SELECT * FROM umls.MRCONSO WHERE code in (%s)) x
                   WHERE x.cui = m.cui 
                     AND x.sab IN (%s)
                   GROUP BY m.CUI
               """ , prm)
```

where the values of `mdr_ids` kept as unquoted presuming `code` is a numeric type of column(*If no, make them quoted too*).